# Cannot write to csv file using BufferedWriter

Tags: csv, servlets

I am trying to append a row at the end of my csv file using the code below

```
public class Register {
public static void add(int k,int m,int id1) throws Exception

{

    ClassLoader classLoader = Register.class.getClassLoader();

    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(classLoader.getResource("data/dataset.csv").getFile()),true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.append("\n");
        bw.append(String.valueOf(id1));
        bw.append(',');
        bw.append(String.valueOf(m));
        bw.append(',');
        bw.append(String.valueOf(k));
        bw.close();



      }catch(IOException ioe){
         System.out.println("Exception occurred:");
         ioe.printStackTrace();
       }

    }
 }
```

I am calling this class from a servlet using a loop as I need to add 5 lines to my csv. Everything runs fine, but nothing gets added to the csv file. Please help.

Comment: When I try your code it works just fine. Is there any error when you run your code?

Comment: no error is shown, but the csv file doesn't get modified. Were you able to append to a csv file using the code??

Comment: Yes, I was able to append data to the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `close` the `FileWriter` object to flush the content into the file as shown below:

```
   FileWriter fw = null;
   BufferedWriter bw = null;
   try{
        fw = new FileWriter(new File(classLoader.
                 getResource("data/dataset.csv").getFile()),true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.append("\n");
        bw.append(String.valueOf(id1));
        bw.append(',');
        bw.append(String.valueOf(m));
        bw.append(',');
        bw.append(String.valueOf(k));
        bw.close();
     }catch(IOException ioe){
         System.out.println("Exception occurred:");
         ioe.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           if(bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }
            if(fw != null) {
                fw.close();
            }
     }
```

As a side note, ensure that you are closing the resources (like the writer objects above) inside the finally block (which you are not doing).

Comment: It didn't work,  the code executes without error but nothing gets appended to csv file. Please suggest what can be a possible solution.